# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string in Django social login

Tags: python, django, forms, google-signin

I am using social-auth-app-django for Google authentication. Whenever I am trying to use google sign-in or admin page, I am facing this error.
[image]

I have added everything correctly in settings.py , views and templates.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\utils.py", line 50, in get_backend
    return BACKENDSCACHE[name]
KeyError: 'google-oauth2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Santosh Chirag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openid\oidutil.py", line 112, in importElementTree
    ElementTree.XML('<unused/>')
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\defusedxml\common.py", line 113, in fromstring
    parser = DefusedXMLParser(target=_TreeBuilder(),
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\defusedxml\ElementTree.py", line 68, in __init__
    _XMLParser.__init__(self, html, target, encoding)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py", line 45, in wrapper
    request.backend = load_backend(request.social_strategy,
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    Backend = get_backend(BACKENDS, name)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\utils.py", line 53, in get_backend
    load_backends(backends, force_load=True)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\utils.py", line 35, in load_backends
    backend = module_member(auth_backend)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py", line 61, in module_member
    module = import_module(mod)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py", line 55, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\google.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .open_id import OpenIdAuth
  File "C:\Data Science\python_files\temop\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\open_id.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openid.consumer.consumer import Consumer, SUCCESS, CANCEL, FAILURE
  File "C:\Users\Santosh Chirag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openid\consumer\consumer.py", line 196, in <module>
    from openid.consumer.discover import discover, OpenIDServiceEndpoint, \
  File "C:\Users\Santosh Chirag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openid\consumer\discover.py", line 22, in <module>
    from openid.yadis.etxrd import nsTag, XRDSError, XRD_NS_2_0
  File "C:\Users\Santosh Chirag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openid\yadis\etxrd.py", line 31, in <module>
    SafeElementTree = importSafeElementTree()
  File "C:\Users\Santosh Chirag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openid\oidutil.py", line 83, in importSafeElementTree
    return importElementTree(module_names)
  File "C:\Users\Santosh Chirag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openid\oidutil.py", line 117, in importElementTree
    'Not using ElementTree library %r because it failed to '
    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

The error seems to be with the social-auth-app-django module.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'#
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'SOCIAL_GOOGLE_KEY'  #Paste CLient Key
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'SECRET KEY'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
```

**login.html**

```
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}" class="google btn"><i class="fa fa-google fa-fw">
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback from the console!

Comment: @KlausD., I have added the error traceback

Comment: Show the code where you are connecting to google

Comment: And the config related to social auth.

Comment: @KlausD. Done that. It seems to be working sometimes, the next day or the  other it stops working again

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG did you figure this one out? If so please let us know the fix, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and solved it by switching the python version in my virtual environment.

It was from a conflict between one django dependency and the python version. The error occurred in a `python 3.8` virtual env, on django 2. Creating a new virtual environment in `python 3.6`, and re-installing all requirements fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.8 broke features of defusexml 0.5.0. Instead of downgrading python from 3.8 to 3.6, you can upgrade defusexml to 0.6.0. The issue was fixed [here](https://github.com/tiran/defusedxml/issues/34).